# Self-disposing timer

Tags: c#, timer

How can I automatically dispose of, and nullify, a timer after it's elapsed?

The `sender` is a random object with no method; I can't dynamically access the original timer via the EventHandler.

Another function will want to check if this timer is null, or running (and interrupt it).

I could run logic such as:

`if (timer != null && timer.Enabled)` but I'd rather `if (timer != null)`

I could also instantiate the variable with a dummy timer, and simply check if this is enabled, but I know if this variable were to suddenly become null, the program would crash.

Should I just use the prior if statement; won't these timers in memory start to add up?

EDIT:

```
static void Main()
{
    Timer timer = null;
    timer = new Timer(5000);
    timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => {
        var T = (Timer)sender;
        T.Dispose();
        T = null;
        Console.WriteLine(T);
    };
    timer.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(timer);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The sender is a random object with no method

It's not. The object is your timer. You just need to cast it back to its original type:

```
private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var timer = (Timer)sender;
    timer.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise that it is handled like that. Would I be able to set it to null, inside of itself?

Comment: You don't set an object to null, it doesn't mean anything. You set a reference to an object to null. If you don't reference your timer anywhere, then it'll be garbage collected after you disable/dispose it

Comment: I casted the sender, before disposing and then nullifying it, and then logged both the sender and the original timer. The sender is nulled but the original timer remains, showing that it's not the same timer (or reference).

Comment: If you were able to log the original timer, it means de facto that you still have a reference to that timer (the one you used to log). How do you retrieve the original timer?

Comment: Yup. The `Console.WriteLine(timer)` is keeping the object alive. I think you should read a bit about how memory is managed in .NET. Long story short, there is a background process, called the garbage collector, that runs from time to time (when exactly doesn't matter). When it runs, it browses the contents of the memory, and clear any object that is not referenced anymore. But since you keep a reference to it in your `while` loop, it'll never be cleared. Just trust the garbage collector, make sure the timer is disabled and not referenced, and it'll eventually be cleared

Comment: I need it to be nulled, right after elapsing, as another function will be checking the value. Will I need to use a pointer, to the original timer, inside the eventHandler, instead of creating a new T variable? If so, how could this be done?

Comment: Just to be clear, you can't nullify a timer. You can only nullify the references to it. Your other function will be keeping a reference to the timer, so you have two solutions: either somehow nullify that reference, or just check the `IsEnabled` property, since you know it'll never be null. It's not a problem if you keep a single timer in memory. If you later create a new one, I suppose you'll overwrite your reference, and therefore the previous timer will be cleared

Comment: I want to nullify the original `timer` reference, not the timer itself, is this possible from the eventhandler? The code in the question nullifies a 
 seperate reference created within the function

Comment: Only if you have access to that reference

Comment: would the `ref` keyword be relevant ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139683/discussion-between-kevin-gosse-and-tobiq).